# How do Geniuses and Hunters interact?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, genius-the-transgression

When playing a mixed White Wolf game, how should **Genius: The Transgression**'s Havoc rules interact with Hunters from **Hunter: The Vigil**? Do they count as humans, or are they supernatural enough themselves not to trigger it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On page 270 of **Genius: The Transgression**, it says that "untemplated humans" are capable of triggering Havoc. Hunters of the first two Tiers don't have a template, so they're considered normal for these purposes. However, Hunters of Tier III should probably count as supernatural for this purpose; if you've got monster parts implanted in you, experimental government tech, boons from Satan's daughter or magical artifacts at your disposal, you're probably okay with mad science.

Comment: Page 55 of Hunter: The vigil says "Step 5: Add Hunter Template", and lists Profession underneath (among other things). Doesn't that mean any character with a Profession is templated? But on the flipside, there's nothing supernatural about a Profession (or is there? I'm really not familiar with Hunter)

Comment: @Yamikuronue You're correct; there's nothing supernatural about a profession -- it's a way of giving depth to characters that would be otherwise mechanically ordinary. Having read both games, I believe that the intent is preserved by treating hunters without Endowments as "lacking a Template," despite using the templating system to build them as per **The World of Darkness** and **H:tV**.

Comment: Alright, cool :) That does make sense.